# How to extract values from multidimensional array grouped by some value inside it using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:-

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [id] => 10 [group] => 11 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [id] => 11 [group] => 13 )
 [2] => Array ( [id] => 12 [group] => 13 ) 
 [3] => Array ( [id] => 13 [group] => 13 ) 
 [4] => Array ( [id] => 14 [group] => 16 ) 
 [5] => Array ( [id] => 15 [group] => 16 ) 
 [6] => Array ( [id] => 16 [group] => 16 )  
)
```

For each different group in this array i want to create array that stores id's.
In my example i have 3 groups, so i want to get 3 arrays like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 10)

Array ( [0] => 11
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 13)

Array ( [0] => 14
        [1] => 15
        [2] => 16)
```

Is it possible if it is how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you get started.
https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_icold.php

```
<?php // demo/temp_icold.php
/**
 * Manipulate multi-dimensional arrays
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422046/how-to-extract-values-from-multidimensional-array-grouped-by-some-value-inside-i
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


$original = Array (
 '0' => Array ( 'id' => 10, 'group' => 11 ),
 '1' => Array ( 'id' => 11, 'group' => 13 ),
 '2' => Array ( 'id' => 12, 'group' => 13 ),
 '3' => Array ( 'id' => 13, 'group' => 13 ),
 '4' => Array ( 'id' => 14, 'group' => 16 ),
 '5' => Array ( 'id' => 15, 'group' => 16 ),
 '6' => Array ( 'id' => 16, 'group' => 16 ),
);

print_r($original);

foreach ($original as $arr)
{
   $ndx = 'group' . $arr['group'];
   $out[$ndx][] = $arr['id'];
}

print_r($out);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this will do for the task i had, will you mind to provide me some documentations to read on this topic? i read php documentation, everything i could find on stackoverflow here, but still have very slight idea of how this works. Thank you again!

Comment: @iColdBeZero I provided a brief explanation of this methodology on my answer, but the basic idea is to provide indexes to your result array that act as groups. Then add to the corresponding index that represents your group. Look more into indexing arrays and the `foreach` loop for more info though.

Comment: It takes some time to learn PHP (or any other language).  In my experience the resources at SitePoint are really good.

Comment: @iColdBeZero  this is not your expected outcome what this code is giving:-https://eval.in/839853  . So what make you to mark this as an accepted answer?

Comment: @AlivetoDie This is exactly what they wanted. Are you maybe being confused by the input array being printed first?

Comment: @yanman1234  no i am not confused. check question desired output and my answer link output :- https://eval.in/839850. And now compare it with current selected answer output:-https://eval.in/839853

Comment: @Alive to Die: I don't get why you think there is something wrong with the answer.  It produces the three arrays that the question asked for.  There are lots of ways to get the answer and organize the data.  What are we missing here?

Comment: i din't say it's wrong. It's not exactly what shown by OP that's it. Leave it man. Op moved out, so we have to moved out too

Comment: @AlivetoDie The only difference between your result and this result is the names used for grouping in the mutidim array, which was not specified by the OP. So this is very much correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through many different methods, but the simplest is probably a [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop. In the example below I am looping through `$a` (your sample array) and building up a new array called `$grouped` with the index as the `group` attributes value.

In my example I am not duplicating the ID's inside of `$group`. If you wanted duplicates you could remove the second `if` statement.

```
$a = [ 
    ['id' => 10, 'group' => 11],
    ['id' => 11, 'group' => 13],
    ['id' => 12, 'group' => 13],
    ['id' => 13, 'group' => 13],
    ['id' => 14, 'group' => 16],
    ['id' => 15, 'group' => 16],
    ['id' => 16, 'group' => 16],
];

$grouped = [];
foreach ($a as $entry) {
    if (! array_key_exists($entry['group'], $grouped)) {
        $grouped[$entry['group']] = [];
    }
    if (! in_array($entry['id'], $grouped[$entry['group']])) {
        $grouped[$entry['group']][] = $entry['id'];
    }
}

var_dump($grouped);
```

The example outputs the following:

```
array(3) {
  [11]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [13]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(11)
    [1]=>
    int(12)
    [2]=>
    int(13)
  }
  [16]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(14)
    [1]=>
    int(15)
    [2]=>
    int(16)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your first `if` in the `foreach` is redundant since PHP automatically instantiates arrays for new indices.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result_array = array();
foreach($array_name as $sub_array){
    $result_array[$sub_array['group']][] = $sub_array['id'];
}
```

This will loop through your input array and create a result two dimensional array indexed by your group values. To extract a group result just index for the group as such: `$result_array['GROUP_NUMBER'];`

Comment: Basically what mine does except WAYYY more simple, I guess I reinvented the wheel :P

Comment: I have had to write this functionality far too often, so I have found a fairly compact way of doing it by now

Comment: I love it honestly but I feel like it's very complex for a new PHP developer :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this:

```
<?php

    $arr = array(
        array("id"=>10,"group"=>11),
        array("id"=>11,"group"=>13),
        array("id"=>12,"group"=>13),
        array("id"=>13,"group"=>13),
        array("id"=>14,"group"=>16),
        array("id"=>15,"group"=>16),
        array("id"=>16,"group"=>16)
    );

    echo "<pre>".print_r(groupsToArrays($arr),true)."</pre>";

    function groupsToArrays($arr, $groupkey = "group") {
        $main = array();
        $group = 0;
        $arr[] = array("id"=>"end", $groupkey => "0");
        foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
            if($group != $value[$groupkey]) {
                if($key != 0) $main[$group] = $tempArray;
                if($value['id'] == "end") continue;
                $group = $value[$groupkey];
                $tempArray = array();
            }
            $tempArray[] = $value;
        }
        return $main;
    }
```

This function will loop through your array and check the `$groupkey` key and will add every match to it's own array.

This is the return:

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [group] => 11
                )

        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11
                    [group] => 13
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [group] => 13
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 13
                    [group] => 13
                )

        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [group] => 16
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [group] => 16
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 16
                    [group] => 16
                )

        )

)
```

So now you can access that group array by doing:

```
$groups = groupsToArrays($arr);
print_r($groups[$groupID]);
```